# Caching with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-modules

Spring Modules had a @Cacheable annotation:

```
org.springmodules.cache.annotations.Cacheable
```

Now that Spring Module is deprecated, what is the recommendation for caching? And is still still possible to work with ehCache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users of Spring Modules have rather been left out on a limb. There's no direct replacement for `@Cacheable` that I'm aware of.

Spring does have some support for EhCache, though, in the form of `EhCacheFactoryBean` and related classes (see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/package-summary.html)). This gives a pretty easy way of creating and managing EhCache instances, but you then have to make use of it manually.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/ is an ehcache specific replacement for the spring-module cache annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The distribute cache server is memcached. I has api to java.
http://memcached.org/

Comment: You haven't really answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

This project is intended as a direct replacement: http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

This is now found in spring-context.  I have not checked how far back it is, but it is in the 4.1.4.RELEASE.

\org\springframework\cache\annotation\